# How can i check if a files already exist in the List?

Tags: c#

This is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
{
    if (pdf1.Lightnings.Count == 0)
    {
        pdf1.Lightnings.Add(files[i]);
    }
    if (files[i] != pdf1.Lightnings[i])
    {
        pdf1.Lightnings.Add(files[i]);
    }
}
```

Both files and Lightnings are `List<string>`

For example in files I have 33 indexes (files names) and I want to add them to the Lightnings List.
But I want to check that if the file name from the List of files already exist in Lightnings so don't add it again.

The way it is now I'm getting error since when the variable i=1 so the line:

```
if (files[i] != pdf1.Lightnings[i])
```

Throws an error since in Lightnings i have only one index [0] and in i=1 already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**`.Contains`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) method:

```
if (!pdf1.Lightnings.Contains(files[i]))
    pdf1.Lightnings.Add(files[i]);
```

This will check that `files[i]` does not already exist in the collection before adding.

Comment: @JMK: There are a lot of other good answers posted as well.  Mine doesn't require LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using distinct property and foreach loop:

```
var count = 0;
foreach(var file in files.Distinct())
{

    if (pdf1.Lightnings.Count == 0)
    {
        pdf1.Lightnings.Add(file);
    }
    if (files[i] != pdf1.Lightnings[count])
    {
        pdf1.Lightnings.Add(file);
    }
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pdf1.Lightnings.AddRange(files.Distinct());
```

or

```
pdf1.Lightnings = pdf1.Lightnings.Union(files));
```

Comment: This will only work if the code is called once, what if the method is called multiple times with the same file names?

Comment: @James You are right, but It is not clear in the  question and I assumed `Lightnings` is empty initially.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done pretty easily using LINQ, it will also reduce the amount of code you need to write e.g.

```
var itemsToAdd = files.Where(x => !pdf.Lightnings.Contains(x));
pdf.Lightnings.AddRange(itemsToAdd);
```

Even one line if you still found it readable

```
pdf.Lightnings.AddRange(files.Where(x => !pdf.Lightings.Contains(x)));
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the answers already given, if you want a unique list of items, you could use [HashSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead. Of course, whether the HashSet is better than a List depends on your usage, but it guarantees unique values.